# Using EaselJS sprite sheet in existing code

Tags: javascript, sprite-sheet, easeljs

I want to modify existing code which uses an image to animate, and use a sprite sheet instead. I'm using the EaselJS library for this.

The piece of code that creates the objects for animation:

```
function initStageObjects(){

    car = new Car('img/car.png',canvas.width()/2,canvas.height()/2);

}
```

And this is the complete code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){


// Canvas Variables
var canvas = $('#canvas');
var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width();
var canvasHeight = canvas.height();


// Keyboard Variables
var leftKey = 37;
var upKey = 38;
var rightKey = 39;
var downKey = 40;

// Keyboard event listeners
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode == leftKey){
        car.left = true;
    } else if(keyCode == upKey){
        car.forward = true;
    } else if(keyCode == rightKey){
        car.right = true;
    } else if (keyCode == downKey){
        car.backward = true;
    }
});
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == leftKey){
        car.left = false;
    } else if(keyCode == upKey){
        car.forward = false;
    } else if(keyCode == rightKey){
        car.right = false;
    } else if (keyCode == downKey){
        car.backward = false;
    }
});

// Start & Stop button controlls
var playAnimation = true;

var startButton = $('#startAnimation');
var stopButton = $('#stopAnimation');

startButton.hide();
startButton.click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    stopButton.show();
    playAnimation = true;
    updateStage();
});
stopButton.click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    startButton.show();
    playAnimation = false;
});


// Resize canvas to full screen
function resizeCanvas(){
    canvas.attr('width', $(window).get(0).innerWidth);
    canvas.attr('height', $(window).get(0).innerHeight);
    canvasWidth = canvas.width();
    canvasHeight = canvas.height();
}
resizeCanvas();
$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);


function initialise(){
    initStageObjects();
    drawStageObjects();
    updateStage();
}


// Car object and properties
function Car(src, x, y){        
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = src;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.angle = 90;

    this.topSpeed = 5;
    this.acceleration = 0.1;
    this.reverse = 0.1;
    this.brakes = 0.3;
    this.friction = 0.05;
    this.handeling = 15;
    this.grip = 15;
    this.minGrip = 5;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.drift = 0;

    this.left = false;
    this.up = false;
    this.right = false;
    this.down = false;
}


// Create any objects needed for animation        
function initStageObjects(){

    car = new Car('img/car.png',canvas.width()/2,canvas.height()/2);

}


function drawStageObjects(){
    context.save();
    context.translate(car.x,car.y);
    context.rotate((car.angle + car.drift) * Math.PI/180);    

    context.drawImage(car.image, -25 , (-47 + (Math.abs(car.drift / 3))));    

    // context.fillRect(-5, -5, 10, 10);
    context.restore();

}


function clearCanvas(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);  
    context.beginPath();
}


function updateStageObjects(){

    // Faster the car is going, the worse it handels
    if(car.handeling > car.minGrip){
        car.handeling = car.grip - car.speed;
    }
    else{
        car.handeling = car.minGrip + 1;
    }


    // Car acceleration to top speed
    if(car.forward){
        if(car.speed < car.topSpeed){
            car.speed = car.speed + car.acceleration;
        }            
    }        
    else if(car.backward){
        if(car.speed < 1){
            car.speed = car.speed - car.reverse;    
        }
        else if(car.speed > 1){
            car.speed = car.speed - car.brakes;
        }
    }


    // Car drifting logic
    if(car.forward && car.left){
        if(car.drift > -35){
            car.drift = car.drift - 3;    
        }
    }
    else if(car.forward && car.right){
        if(car.drift < 35){
            car.drift = car.drift + 3;    
        }
    }
    else if(car.forward && !car.left && car.drift > -40 && car.drift < -3){
        car.drift = car.drift + 3;
    }
    else if(car.forward && !car.right && car.drift < 40 && car.drift > 3){
        car.drift = car.drift - 3;
    }

    if(car.drift > 3){
        if(!car.forward && !car.left){
            car.drift = car.drift - 4;
        }
    }

    else if(car.drift > -40 && car.drift < -3){
        if(!car.forward && !car.right){
            car.drift = car.drift + 4;
        }
    }


    // General car handeling when turning    
    if(car.left){
        car.angle = car.angle - (car.handeling * car.speed/car.topSpeed);

    } else if(car.right){
        car.angle = car.angle + (car.handeling * car.speed/car.topSpeed);    

    }


    // Use this div to display any info I need to see visually
    $('#stats').html("Score: 0");


    // Constant application of friction / air resistance
    if(car.speed > 0){
        car.speed = car.speed - car.friction;
    } else if(car.speed < 0) {
        car.speed = car.speed + car.friction;
    }


    // Update car velocity (speed + direction)
    car.vy = -Math.cos(car.angle * Math.PI / 180) * car.speed;
    car.vx = Math.sin(car.angle * Math.PI / 180) * car.speed;    

    // Plot the new velocity into x and y cords
    car.y = car.y + car.vy;
    car.x = car.x + car.vx;
}


// Main animation loop
function updateStage(){
    clearCanvas();
    updateStageObjects();
    drawStageObjects();        

    if(playAnimation){
        setTimeout(updateStage, 25);
    }
}


// Initialise the animation loop
initialise();

});
});//]]>  
// JavaScript Document
```

How could i replace the image being used by the sprite i created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you maybe could implement a `createjs.SpriteSheet` into a non-Createjs/non-EaselJS project I would **strongly** recommend you **not** to do that, EaselJS-classes where not designed to be used as single modular classes in any kind of project, they best work together in the framework. In the end you probably will need more time and probably end up with more code by trying get everything to work than with just converting your (yet still small) project to EaselJS all together. So learn something new today and refacture your project to EaselJS ;-)

---

**but if you want more work, continue reading:**
A `createjs.SpriteSheet` basically only handles SpriteSheet data and you can use `mySpriteSheet.getFrame(int);` to get the image and the source-rect to that frame so you can draw it to your canvas. **But** a SpriteSheet alone won't handle animations for you, so you would have to advance the "playhead" every frame yourself(go back to frame 0 if at the end ect...), or you can implement another createjs-class called `createjs.BitmapAnimation` - however, drawing this to your canvas would again require additional code or yet an additional createjs-class: you see where this is getting.